Is there a compatible way to create a dynamic date in .http files?
I want to use .http files across our engineering team instead of Postman as it is easier to manage these next to the code rather than in a Postman collection. However, some team members would rather use IntelliJ tools and others VSCode. This sadly exposes the discrepancies between how this format is implemented by different tools.
IntelliJ
### Example Requests
< {% 
 let todaysDate = new Date();
 request.variables.set("todaysDate", todaysDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
 %}
GET https://example.com?date={{todaysDate}}

httpyac in VS Code
### Example Requests
{{
 let todaysDate = new Date();
 exports.todaysDate = todaysDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
}}
GET https://example.com?date={{todaysDate}}

Is there a way to write this once that works in both tools? httpyac has some compatibility with ItelliJ, but this one is stumping me.
